# How to disable Xcode compiler warning "Property access result unused - getters should not be used for side effects"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compiler-warnings

I would like to know, how I can disable Xcode compiler warning titled: Property access result unused - getters should not be used for side effects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach would probably be to cast to `void`, or assign to an unused variable (`T unused_var = property_access;`), and add a comment to the line stating why the return value is being discarded. However...

Find the project setting for compiler flags and add:

```
-Wno-unused-getter-return-value
```

This comes from [Clang Options to Control Error and Warning Messages](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#options-to-control-error-and-warning-messages) and [Diagnostics Flags in Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html).

Comment: The best approach would be to switch from dot syntax to a normal method invocation. ;)

Comment: @bbum - I'd forgotten that gives no warning, so its another way but is it the best? Like using the compiler flag it hides that the result isn't used. Clearly "best" here is subjective ;-)

Comment: @CRD Mostly, it doesn't warn for historical reasons.   There is just too much code that has methods like `-(BOOL)doSomething;` and when designing `@property` we couldn't justify making the resulting methods behave significantly differently than regular methods, neither on declaration nor invocation (the one major exception being the `.` requiring strong typing of the object -- this warning being a more minor difference).

Answer (score 1):

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wno-unused-getter-return-value" // or whatever

-(void)yourMethodHere{
// generate warning
}

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```